# All Mail folder

Tags: gmail, imap

Every answered on this topic is unsatisfactory. I have a simple request and expect a very simple procedure. I expect you have the expertise and experience to provide an immediate answer.

I need to delete all emails from my All Mail folder without deleting them from my Inbox or Sent mail folder. The reason is that I have an outlook client set up with IMAP sync enabled. When I delete an email from the Gmail All Mail folder, it deletes the email from the Gmail In Box folder. Then it deletes from my client when it syncs the folder using the IMAP settings.

You need to provide step by step instructions on how to delete from the ALL Mail folder without deleting from the client when IMAP sync is enabled.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. What web application are you using? Also show what you tried and a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed that Gmail was mentioned (using all lower case)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the very simple answer to your request: In Gmail **it's not possible** "to delete all emails from my All Mail folder without deleting them from my Inbox or Sent mail folder".

Related

- [Is there a way to make Gmail stop storing every email twice?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/114060/88163)
- [All Mail; deleting from disappeared my folder items as well!](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/138273/88163)